# Wildfly redeployment of war file

Tags: jboss, wildfly, war

I always hit an error when trying to redeploy the same war file into the Wildfly. Anyone know what does the error below means and how to solve it?

Error as below:
Cannot upload deployment: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./warfile" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./warfile: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception while trying to start [TaskExecutionSupportServiceApplication] - component skipped Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception while trying to start [TaskExecutionSupportServiceApplication] - component skipped Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception while trying to start [TaskExecutionSupportServiceApplication] - component skipped Caused by: org.apache.ftpserver.FtpServerConfigurationException: Failed to bind to address 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:21, check configuration Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind"}}

Answer (score 2):

The following line contains the root cause:

```
org.apache.ftpserver.FtpServerConfigurationException: Failed to bind to address 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:21
```

It looks like you are starting a FTP server on port 21 that is not shutdown when the application is undeployed. The new deployment tries to open the same port and gets an error from the OS.